# How to turn off the IsAddingCompleted on BlockingCollection

Tags: c#

There is something that i can't understand on the BlockingCollection class.
this is the scenario:

1. thread1 is adding n items to the BlockingCollection and mark the BlockingCollection as AddingCompleted
2. Meanwhile thread2 wait till thread1 mark the BlockingCollection as AddingCompleted and starting to Take all the item out of the BlockingCollection and display on the console.
3. the BlockingCollection is now empty and thread1 try to add more 3 items. 
   But this trying will throw an exception "The collection has been marked as complete with regards to additions."

My question:
Is there any way to add more items after AddingCompleted ( without create new BlockingCollection ) and to use the same display items of thread2 ?

Comment: simple answer : no :) If you still want to add items, then you shouldn't call AddingCompleted();

Comment: "AddingCompleted marks the BlockingCollection<T> instances as not accepting any more additions."

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Your #2 step doesn't make much sense to me; how does "thread2" wait for "thread1"? The point of `BlockingCollection` is that a consumer can be made to block until there is something to consume; but how do you have your consumer wait until `AddingCompleted()` has been called? Normally, the reason you'd call that method is so that the consumer _doesn't_ block (i.e. the consuming enumerable reaches its end, allowing the consumer thread to process past the enumeration of the collection). Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask